# Jhipster Azure Cosmos DB SQL API

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, jhipster

Does Jhipster support Azures Cosmos DB SQL API? In the below site, it was mentioned that Jhipster  is compatible with Cosmos DB - cassandra and Mongo DB API, but nothing mentioned about SQL API

https://www.jhipster.tech/azure/#nosql-databases

Did any one successfully implemented Jhipster with Cosmos DB SQL API?

Answer (score 1):

If jHipster supports Cassandra and MongoDB (as the documentation states), then you would need to use Cosmos DB with those APIs. The SQL API is a different API layer for interacting with Cosmos DB, and if the jHipster documentation doesn't state is supports SQL API, then it doesn't.

> CosmosDB is a globally distributed, managed database from Microsoft. It is compatible at the API level with Cassandra and MongoDB, so it can be used with a JHipster application that is generated using those technologies.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I was wondering why jHipster people haven't implemented to use SQL API.